# If else condition cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, if-statement, aws-cloudformation

I would like to populate a value in cloudformation depending on input parameter. I want to assign `Name` as either `test-svc.abc.com` or `svc.abc.com` depending on whether environment name is `prod` or not. If the environnment name is `prod` then the value should be `svc.abc.com` otherwise it should always be `{env-name}-svc.abc.com`.

I have the following expression:

```
Name: !Join [ '-', [ !Ref EnvironmentName, !Ref 'HostedZoneName' ] ]
```

In the above expression, `HostedZoneName` will be passed as `svc.abc.com` and the value of `EnvironmentName` could be `test, release or prod`. So the conditions should be evaluated as:

```
Inputs: HostedZoneName -> svc.abc.com, EnvironmentName -> test
Output: test-svc.abc.com

Inputs: HostedZoneName -> svc.abc.com, EnvironmentName -> release
Output: release-svc.abc.com

Inputs: HostedZoneName -> svc.abc.com, EnvironmentName -> 1234567
Output: 1234567-svc.abc.com

Inputs: HostedZoneName -> svc.abc.com, EnvironmentName -> prod
Output: svc.abc.com
```

It's basically ternary operator.

```
Name = EnvironmentName.equals("prod") ? HostedZoneName : EnvironmentName + "-" + HostedZoneName
```

Struggling with if else condition in CloudFormation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [Cloudformation Conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html). You can use them to define if-statements  using `Fn::If`

Then you can use this condition in the Resources section to define how to build your `HostedZoneName`.

Here's an example. You'll probably need to do something like this:

```
...
 "Conditions" : {
    "CreateProdResources" : {"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "EnvType"}, "prod"]}
  },

...

"Properties" : {
    "HostedZoneName" : {
      "Fn::If" : [
        "CreateProdResources",
        "svn.abc.com",
        {"Fn::Sub": "${Environment}-svc.abc.com"}
      ]}
  },
```

Answer (score 10):

Based on the answer posted by @rdas, I've implemented below expression in YAML format:

```
...
Conditions: 
  IsProductionEnvironment: !Equals [ !Ref EnvironmentName, prod ]
...

...
Name: !If [IsProductionEnvironment, !Ref 'HostedZoneName', !Join [ '-', [ !Ref EnvironmentName, !Ref 'HostedZoneName' ] ]]
...
```

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by using !sub in !if. below is the example where I was looking for the domain prefix (dev,qa,stage) for the non-prod environment.

your non-prod bucket name will be

```
dev.mydomain.xyz.com
qa.mydomain.xyz.com
stage.mydomain.xyz.com
```

and prod bucket name will be

```
mydomain.xyz.com
```

clouformation Yaml exm

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: 'AWS cloudformation template for admin panel s3 bucket. '
Parameters:
  WebBucketName:
    Description: Enter the name of the application
    Type: String
    Default: mydomain.xyz.com
  Environment:
    Description: Enter the environmet name from allowed values
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - qa
      - dev
      - prod
      - stage
Conditions:
  CreateProdResources: !Equals [!Ref Environment, prod]
  CreatedevResources: !Equals [!Ref Environment, dev]
  CreateqaResources: !Equals [!Ref Environment, qa]
  CreatestageResources: !Equals [!Ref Environment, stage]
  MultiCondition: !Or
    - !Condition CreatedevResources
    - !Condition CreateqaResources
    - !Condition CreatestageResources

Resources:
  WebS3AdminPanel:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName:
        !If [MultiCondition, !Sub "${Environment}.${WebBucketName}", !Sub "${WebBucketName}" ]
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: test
      WebsiteConfiguration:
        IndexDocument: index.html
        ErrorDocument: error.html
      AccessControl: PublicRead
```